# I want to compare two values having special character in perl but this is failing

Tags: perl, if-statement, special-characters

I am getting following values for `$var1` and `$var2`;
`$var1` is:

```
Dec 12 17:08:00  webui[1310]: USER:admin@10.10.200.27 COMMAND:<local-userdb-ap add mac-address "00:0b:86:68:03:a6" ap-group "remoteAP" ap-name "HBF_03-56_RAP1" description "RAP deployed in HarbourFront" > -- command executed successfully
```

`$var2` is also the same.

When I am doing just the comparison:

```
if( $var1 eq $var2)
{
  print "OK";
}
else
{
  print "Not OK";
}
```

This is not working. 
I tries chomp also for this two variable. But still no use.
Please suggest..Whether this is possible to compare strings like this?

New Edit::

$var1 is

```
Dec 12 17:08:00  webui[1310]: USER:admin@10.10.200.27 COMMAND:<local-userdb-ap add mac-address "00:0b:86:68:03:a6" ap-group "remoteAP" ap-name "HBF_03-56_RAP1" description "RAP deployed in HarbourFront" > -- command executed successfully
```

and var2 is also same.  When I try to comapre this using If statement, this is not working.
Dumper shows following values:

```
$VAR1 = "Dec 12 17:08:00  webui[1310]: USER:admin\@10.10.200.27 COMMAND:<local-userdb-ap add mac-address \"00:0b:86:68:03:a6\" ap-group \"remoteAP\" ap-name \"HBF_03-56_RAP1\" description \"RAP deployed in HarbourFront\" > -- command executed successfully ";

$VAR2 = "Dec 12 17:08:00  webui[1310]: USER:admin\@10.10.200.27 COMMAND:<local-userdb-ap add mac-address \"00:0b:86:68:03:a6\" ap-group \"remoteAP\" ap-name \"HBF_03-56_RAP1\" description \"RAP deployed in HarbourFront\" > -- command executed successfully ";
```

In this also, $VAR1 and $VAR2 looks same. But If statement is saying this is not equal.

Comment: Print out both values with the `Data::Dumper` module: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper($var1, $var2);`. Could you post the exact output of that?

Comment: Where are the `$var` variables coming from?

Comment: Variable are coming from Sqlite database.

Comment: How are you assigning the strings to `$var1` and `$var2`?

Comment: Wonderful: a “Heisenbug”! This is difficult. What perl version are you using (`perl -v` output)? Are the values Data::Dumper sees really equal? Please insert the following code and report the error message. `our $VAR1; our $VAR2; eval Dumper($var1, $var2); $VAR1 eq $VAR2 or die "Serialized not same"; $var1 eq $VAR1 or die "var1 not same"; $var2 eq $VAR2 or die "var2 not same"; $var1 eq $var2 or die "original not same"; die "none";`. It might also be interesting to see the internal representation: `use Devel::Peek (); Devel::Peek::Dump($var1); Devel::Peek::Dump($var2);`.

Comment: If the $vars are printing properly to Dumper, but not evaluated as equal, then something strange is going on. How do you get the strings into each variable?

Answer (score 0):

Dumper output can be wrong(it not shows internal scalar flags).
Try 
Devel:Peek module, it exports Dump method and you will see all flags.

For example, if you have 2 vars, try this code:

```
$var1 = unpack('b*', $var1);
$var1 = pack('b*', $var1);

$var2 = unpack('b*', $var2);
$var2 = pack('b*', $var2);

if ($var1 eq $var2) {
    print 'equal';
}
else {
    print 'not equal';
}
```

where $var1 and $var2 your strings.

If proplem with utf8 flag, you can use decode_utf8 and encode_utf8, I hope, this will help.